# Carriage bolt rotation

Tags: tools

I am putting to together a dip station (for the exercise) in my house that I bought online.

The damn carriage bolt is turning with the nut. I know how to use tools but not exactly "Mr D.I.Y".  What can I do to get the damn thing to stop rotating?!

Comment: Have you tried tapping the damn thing into the wood a bit, allowing the shoulders on the bolt to grab?

Comment: Lol I knew I might get stick for that....the dip bars /station is seperate....it has two horizontal pieces, two vertical, a crossbar and two handles.....I've connected the verticals to horizontal parts without issue. But the crossbar between em is where I've come unstuck....I would share a pic but cannot see an option to.

Comment: *not exactly "Mr D.I.Y"* - so do you know what **cross-threaded** means? Are you sure you haven't? Are you SURE you're sure?

Comment: Yes I am sure on both accounts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have clamping pliers, commonly called Vise-Grips, and you can get some bite on the head of the bolt, a solid grip will enable you to accomplish your objective.

Alternatively, cutting a slot in the head to accept a straight-blade screwdriver will work. If you cannot get to the head side conveniently, cutting a slot in the opposite end may also work. These slotting actions will require a steady hand on a hacksaw or the use of a hobby tool commonly called a Dremel tool, aka rotary cutter or rotary grinder.

Yet another non-destructive option, if the bolt is of sufficient length is to add two nuts to the threaded portion, tighten each one against the other and use a wrench to hold the bolt while turning the other nut as appropriate.

Comment: You could buy the next size larger diameter carriage bolt since the one they supplied has stripped out the area where the square part of the bolt normally grabs so the bolt won't turn. I would check the hole where this bolt goes to see if the hole was drilled too large for the carriage bolt they supplied.

Comment: @d.george although then, you would also need to drill the hole larger (assuming it's wood) or potentially overstress (if it's metal).  If it is metal and it cams out, evaluate if it's too cheaply made to put your weight on.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes these assemble-it-yourself products have different kinds of fasteners to go in different areas of the product. Does the piece through which you are putting the carriage bolt have a square opening? If not, you may have used a hex-headed bolt somewhere else in the assembly that is intended to go where you are attempting to put the carriage bolt.

Comment: Its a square opening...and that thought about the bolts but I doubled checked according to the instructions its correct